# Installing PyQt (for pyuic4) after sip install goes OK: error: PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11 install

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4

After installing `sip`, I keep getting this lovely error message when trying to install `PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11`.

```
mycommandline$ python configure-ng.py --verbose

Querying qmake about your Qt installation...

Determining the details of your Qt installation...

/usr/bin/qmake -o qtdetail.mk qtdetail.pro

make -f qtdetail.mk

g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o qtdetail.o qtdetail.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o qtdetail qtdetail.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtCore -lpthread 

Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation.
```

I can't really figure out what it means. Is it a dependency issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using ubuntu, there's no need to compile from source just to get `pyuic4`. If you install the correct official packages, everything should be included.

Just install either this:

- Python 2: **python-qt4** and **pyqt4-dev-tools**

Or this:

- Python 3: **python3-pyqt4** and **pyqt4-dev-tools**

Comment: didn't have pyqt4-dev-tools installed, I appreciate so much!  :)